# Qt/Spyder scaling with 4K display

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, spyder, pyqtgraph

I've recently made the switch from an old macbook pro to a razer blade stealth laptop. I have many programs that I've written that have pyqt4 GUIs, and I usually do most of my coding in spyder. Upon switching to a computer with a 4K screen spyder has become unusable as it does not scale properly, in addition all the GUIs that I have written don't scale correctly and are thus unusable.

Does anyone have any experience with this problem and/or have any tips on how to get these things to scale correctly on high DPI screens?

Comment: If the most recent Qt 4.8 doesn't have support for high-dpi displays, then you'll have to move to Qt 5. It works fine there.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the info.
If I just install Qt 5 will spyder automatically register this or will I have to update some settings somewhere?

Comment: For the record, moving to Qt5 does not fix the issue.
I downloaded the winpython version that comes with Qt5 and spyder still looks very distorted right out of the box

Comment: You need to update spyder to version 3 (currently in beta) to use Qt5; see https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases/tag/v3.0.0b4

Comment: I am using spyder3 already

Comment: You must use spyder3 *and* your code must be using qt5, not qt4.

Comment: I understand but spyder3 itself is not even scaling properly, so I don't see how this could be an issue of my code

Answer (score 0):

The next version of Spyder (3.0.0) will natively support high dpi screen and makes use for vector icons.

You can try the latest beta (Spyder 3.0.0 beta4) if you want to be an early adopter.

Check out the talk on "what's new in Spyder 3.0" at the last Scipy conference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5boKDo1C144

Comment: The most current version of winpython also comes with spyder 3.0.0 beta4. Still no luck

Comment: It does have both of those things

Comment: by still no luck, you mean that spyder is still not making use of highdpi or only your qt4 programs.

Comment: Spyder is still not scaling properly I mean

Comment: Can you please open an issue in the issue tracker of spyder (https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues). StackOverflow may not be the best medium for this!

Comment: I am having still the same problem with windows 10 spyder 3.3.1. very poorly scaled.